# How to cut (remove) 1/2" x 30" Innova waterproof flooring

Tags: laminate

A new dishwasher was just delivered and the installers informed me that the flooring (installed with the old dishwasher in place) is preventing them from removing the old dishwasher. A 1/2" x 30" section of the flooring (where it meets the cabinet holding the dishwasher) must be removed to create the space needed to remove the old dishwasher and install the new one. *Note: The flooring is "floating" above the floor - it  is not affixed to it.** Must the entire plank be removed to cut this piece or can it be done with the plank in place? If the plank can remain in place, what is the best method to achieve this?

Comment: Will the new dishwasher cover the cut?  If not would lift the whole section and then replace.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually, the piece to be removed sits under the cabinet overhang, so, with the DW in place, it won't be visible

Comment: I imagine that it is a tight/small space for most saws.  One of those oscillating multi-tools will probably work best in a small space(dishwasher within inches or less).

Comment: Consider cutting the old dishwasher, not the flooring.

Comment: Or at least removing the toe kick on the old d/w and cutting the floor as close to the frame as possible.  Likely the cut will be covered by the new kick.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your replies. I managed to find a neighbor who owned an oscillating saw and by a fortunate coincidence, the right blade/attachment. The flooring (installed after the old dishwasher was installed) decreased the size of the opening by 0.125 inches, which was just enough to prevent removing the old dishwasher (or installing the new one). To create the space needed to remove the appliance and avoid damaging the counter top's tile, I used the oscillating saw to cut a small piece of the flooring (~0.15 inches x 36 inches). Thanks again for your replies, they were very helpful!